# Un-named JSON array field validation in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a un-named JSON array like this from the response and would like to check whether it contains `"confirmationNumber": "pqrs"` or not. May I know how can I check that in Karate?

```
[
    {
        "id": 145,
        "confirmationNumber": "abcd"
    },{
        "id": 723
        "confirmationNumber": "pqrs"
    }
    ,{
        "id": 7342
        "confirmationNumber": "sfeq"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`karate.filter()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-filter) is good for these situations:

```
* def response = 
"""
[
   {
      "id":145,
      "confirmationNumber":"abcd"
   },
   {
      "id":723,
      "confirmationNumber":"pqrs"
   },
   {
      "id":7342,
      "confirmationNumber":"sfeq"
   }
]
"""
* def fun = function(x){ return x.confirmationNumber == 'pqrs' }
* def found = karate.filter(response, fun)
* match found == '#[1]'
```

Also see examples of JsonPath: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

EDIT: apologies, there is a much simpler way, please [read the docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts) !

```
* match response contains { id: '#number', confirmationNumber: 'pqrs' }
* def item = { confirmationNumber: 'pqrs' }
* match response contains '#(^item)'
```